# How is a system for parametrizing a triangular mesh obtained?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am analyzing the article Parameterization of triangular meshes (Michael S. Floater November 10, 2009) and have reached the point where the uniqueness of the solution to a system of linear equations.

> We now describe a general method for constructing a parameterization of
> triangular mesh in $R^3$. We denote by $S$ the set of triangles in the mesh and
> $V$ its vertices and $E$ its edges. We let $Ω_S ⊂ R^3$ be the union of the triangles
> in $S$. Then we define a parameterization of $S$ as a continuous piecewise linear mapping $ψ : Ω_S → R^2$. Then $ψ$ maps each vertex, edge, and triangle of $S$ to a corresponding vertex, edge, and triangle in $R^2$. Such a mapping is completely determined by the points $ψ(v), v ∈ V$. Let $V_I$ denote the interior vertices of $S$ and $V_B$ the boundary ones. The boundary vertices of $S$ form a polygon $∂S$ in $R^3$ which we call the boundary polygon of $S$. Two distinct vertices $v$ and $w$ in $S$ are neighbours if they are the end points of some edge
> in $S$. For each $v ∈ V$ , let $$N_v = {w ∈ V : [w, v] ∈ E},$$ the set of neighbours of $v$, where $E = E(S)$ is the set of edges in $S$.
> The first step of the method is to choose any points $ψ(v) ∈ R^2$, for $v ∈ V_B$, such that the boundary polygon $∂S$ of $S$ is mapped into a simple polygon $ψ(∂S)$ in the plane. In the second step, for $v ∈ V_I$ , we choose a set of strictly positive values $λ_{vw}$, for $w ∈ N_v$, such that $$ \sum_{w∈N_v}λ_{vw} = 1. (3)$$
> Then we let the points $ψ(v)$ in $R^2$, for $v ∈ V_I$ , be the unique solutions of the
> linear system of equations $$ ψ(v) = \sum_{w∈N_v}λ_{vw}ψ(w), v ∈ V_I . (4)$$
> Since these equations force each point ψ(v) to be a convex combination of its neighbouring points $ψ(w)$, we call $ψ$ a convex combination mapping.
> Let us take a closer look at the linear system. We must show that it has a unique solution. To this end, note that it can be rewritten in the form
> $$ψ(v) − \sum_{w∈N_v∩V_I}λ_{vw}ψ(w) = \sum_{w∈N_v∩V_B}λ_{vw}ψ(w), v ∈ VI . (5)$$
> This can be written as the matrix equation
> $$Ax = b,$$
> where $x = (ψ(w))_{w∈V_I}$ is the column vector of unknowns in some arbitrary ordering, $b$ is the column vector whose elements are the right hand sides of (5), and the matrix $A = (a_{vw})_{v,w∈V_I}$ has dimension $n × n$, with $n = |V_I|$,
> and elements
> \begin{equation}
> a_{vw} =
>     \begin{cases}
>       1, w = v,\\
>       −λ_{vw}, w ∈ Nv,\\
>       0, otherwise
>     \end{cases}\,.
> \end{equation}

I don't understand where the $a_{vw}$ values come from. How can this be calculated, please tell me?

Comment: They have written the definition of $a_{vw}$ they have not written the definition of $\lambda_{vw}$ though, at least in the excerpt you posted, i.e. "we choose a set of strictly positive values $\lambda_{vw}$".

Comment: @lightxbulb And another condition is that their sum must be equal to 1

Comment: @lightxbulb My question was rather how to get these 3 cases: 1, $- \lambda_{vw}$ and 0?

Comment: It's just equation 5 rewritten in matrix-vector form: $\psi(v)- \sum_{w \in N_v\cap V_I} \lambda_{vw}\psi(w) = \sum_{w \in N_v \cap V_B} \lambda_{vw}\psi(w)$, now with the definition for $a_{vw}$ and $x= (\psi(w))_{w\in V_I}$ you may rewrite this as $\sum_{w} a_{vw} x_w = b_v$, and since you have $|V_I|$ such equations you can write it as $Ax = b$.